# Using PAM, how is minimum number of days between password changes set?

Tags: password, pam

On my Amazon Linux (RHEL-derived) system, within /etc/login.defs, I've set the minimum number of days between password changes to 1 day: `PASS_MIN_DAYS   1`.

I thought I should be doing that with PAM configuration files in /etc/pam.d/. However, I cannot find any documentation for doing so. Is there a way to control when passwords can be changed using PAM, and what is it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting user Specific password policy:**

One option is to modify user password policy - using `lchage` command.

Below command will set minimum number of days required between pasword changes.

```
lchage --mindays=<days> <username>
```

Below command can be used to see current policy

```
lchage --list <username>
```

**Common Policy for All users:**

To set password policy common for all users in system, you need to edit `PASS_MIN_DAYS` variable in `/etc/login.defs` file.

```
root@ubuntu:~# grep PASS_MIN_DAYS /etc/login.defs 
#   PASS_MIN_DAYS   Minimum number of days allowed between password changes.
PASS_MIN_DAYS   1
```

Above grep listing shows minimum # days required between password changes is 1.

If user tries to reset password before minimum # days set, he/she will get error as listed below.

```
$ passwd
Changing password for test.
(current) UNIX password: 
You must wait longer to change your password
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

While creating user, policy defined in `/etc/login.defs` will be applicable to user being created. Again  `lchage --list` command can be used to see current policy.

Comment: This is specifically the password policy for a specific user, right? I'm concerned with the policy applied to all users, which would be significant the next time a new user is added (likely when I leave and a new admin comes on board).

Comment: Yes Michael , chage is to set policy for specific user. I will edit answer regarding common policy for all users.

Answer (score 1):

You raise an interesting question. Per the login.defs man page, the pass_min_days parameter is only applied to the user at account creation, so changes in /etc/pam.d would be preferable for consistency. However, to the best of my knowledge, the standard pam_unix module (and I guess to a lesser extent pam_cracklib.so) doesn't have any options relating to the date.
There's also `chage`, which manipulates /etc/shadow, nothing in /etc/pam.d/.

Ultimately, I think the answer is you can't manage this value via PAM arguments.